# Errors in Project with Python, Qt, Qml, running on Ubuntu, doesn't have same errors via running Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, qml, pyside2

I have a project, with Python3.10, PySide2, QML and other libs.

If i run this project on Windows 11, i have no QML errors.

But when i run the same project, with same dependencies, the same QML files, but on Ubuntu (tried 20.04, 22.04), it causes a lot of QML errors, like `ReferenceError: model is not defined`, `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, `TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object`, `Context2D: The font families specified are invalid: Arial`, `QSSG.trace_info: OpenGL extensions:` and so go on.

I've installed all dependencies in virtualenv. So, i don't have QtCreator or other Qt libs outside the project. I only added `libxcb-xinerama0`, via checking `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`, bc of this `Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found` error.

That's not a QML file problem, as i think, as long as it works with Windows.

What can cause this behavior on Ubuntu and how can i fix this?

(Don't ask me why i'm trying to launch windows' written project on Linux. Designer was working in Windows, so, it is what it is :)

I will attach any info, if it's necessary for someone. So, just ask. (bc i don't know, what will be usefull from the project and environment as info)

Comment: One issue is easy to solve: the Arial font is indeed usually not installed on Ubuntu, so change to another font. For the other issues it would be good if you could trim the code down to the smallest version that produces one of these errors. This means to provide all the import statements and the code that initializes the application, such that when you type `python question_code.py` in the terminal the error shows. Also provide al full verbatim copy of all the terminal output up to and including the error message.

Comment: Thats a really big project (close to production state). It's kinda problematic to compile a small file. But, without using qml file, all works (but, without gui ofc)). Accidentally find out that sys admin has tested this project on runtime ubuntu and all worked well...

Comment: Is it a bare-bones Ubuntu or is it ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @StephenQuan desktop

Comment: If it is not feasible to trim the real project down, then do it the other way around: start an empty project and begin adding imports and some simple model until it starts producing the error that you ask about. To have a chance of answering the question we need to be able to reproduce the problem without too much guessing - ideally, without any guessing, but just by running a code example that you provide.